# Allow Only Alpha Characters in Python?

Tags: python, validation, character

I am writing a program, part of it requires the input of a name. 
The name can only be alpha and spaces (eg. John Smith) it cannot be John Smith1 
If an invalid character IS entered, I need the program to display an error message and reask the questions. I have got everything but the validation. I'm guessing it goes something like this?

```
name = str(input("What is the customers name? "))
while True:
    if ??????????????????? :
        print("You have entered an invalid character. Enter only name."
        name = str(input("What is the customers name? "))
    else:
          break
```

Can someone please fill in the `?????`s to make the program work?

Comment: Tim O'Reilly will not be pleased if he tries to use your program. Neither will 毛澤東.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I think that would be a question for the teacher that proposed the assignment.

Comment: I would use a while loop over the if construct in the sample code.

Comment: It only needs to be simple. It doesn't need to have any of those functions. The teacher does not know the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [`isalpha()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method of strings.

Since the person will enter names with spaces, you have two options:

1. Split the input by the space (use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split))
2. Take advantage of `string.letters`

For example:

```
   >>> import string
   >>> string.letters
   'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Combine that with a `' '` to get your list of allowed characters. Since this is homework, the rest is up to you.

Comment: can you copy this into my code for me? I'm not sure where to put it.

Comment: I have heard of the isalpha() call, but I have no idea where to put it.

Comment: Instead of using `split()` you can use `replace(" ", "")`.
So instead of the "?????" in the OP example you should put `not the_name.replace(" ", "").isalpha()` which is `True` if the name, without spaces, has got some not-alphabetic characters.

Comment: I have tried replacing ??? with not the_name.replace(" ", "").isalpha() and get syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `replace` method of strings to get rid of white-spaces and then use the `isalpha()` method.

An example:

```
>>> def get_name():
...     name = raw_input('name: ')    # use a simple "input" in python3
...     if not name.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
...             print('Bad name!!!')
...     else:
...             print('Good name!')
... 
>>> get_name()
name: My name
Good name!
>>> get_name()
name: Bad Nam3
Bad name!!!
>>> get_name()
name: Jon Skeet
Good name!
```

Note that this works also with non ascii-letters in python3:

```
#python3
>>> get_name()
name: Accented è
Good name!
>>> get_name()
name: Bad Nam3
Bad name!!!
```

Regular expressions are too complicated for this simple task.
Also because using `[A-Za-z ]+` or similar wont match names with non ASCII letters.
And using `\w` includes digits.

If you don't want to match non-ASCII letters(such as 'è'), then you can try something like this:

```
>>> def get_name():
...     name = raw_input('name: ')   #input in python3
...     try:
...             name.encode('ascii')
...     except UnicodeDecodeError:
...             print('Bad name!!!')
...             return
...     if not name.replace(' ', '').isalpha():
...             print('Bad name!!!')
...     else:
...             print('Good name!')
... 
>>> get_name()
name: Accented è
Bad name!!!
>>> get_name()
name: The nam3
Bad name!!!
>>> get_name()
name: Guido Van Rossum
Good name!
```

Finally, an other way to check is this one:

```
>>> import string
>>> def good_name(name):
...     return not set(name).difference(string.letters + ' ')
... 
>>> good_name('Guivo Van Rossum')
True
>>> good_name('Bad Nam3')
False
```

And you can use it in this way:

```
name = raw_input('name: ')   #input in python3
if good_name(name):
   #stuff for valid names
else:
   #stuff for invalid names
```

Comment: Try not to do the work for the OP, especially since this is homework.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match):

```
^[A-Za-z ]*$
```

is a regex that only matches strings if they consist entirely of ASCII letters and spaces.

To also allow letters of your current locale:

```
^[^\W\d_]*$
```

which is basically the set of alphanumeric characters including accented characters (in the current locale) minus digits and underscore.

Comment: I think regular expressions might not be part of the course yet.

Comment: I think in programming you should have a practical approach if you want to progress

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expressions, something like `[A-Za-z ]+`

It would translate into something like this, if I use Tim's expression:

```
match = re.match(r'^[A-Za-z ]*$', name )
if match :
    print("Correct name");
else:
    print("Invalid chars");
```

Answer (score -1):

To Check the string for alpha I generally use this one. Hope this can help you.

```
import re
def is_alpha_space(name):
    name_nospace = ''.join((name.split()))
    if re.search(r"\W", name_nospace) or len(name_nospace) < 1:
        return False
    return True
name = "Mark Zumkoff"
print(is_alpha_space(name))  # True
name = "Mark Zumkoff@"
print(is_alpha_space(name))  # False
name = "    "
print(is_alpha_space(name))  # False
```