# Use of try/except for input validation?

Tags: python, validation, loops

I am trying to validate user input to check that, when they enter their name, it is more than 2 characters and is alphabetic. I am attempting to do this using try/except as I have been told that it is the best loop for user validation. Unfortunately if the user enters characters that are not alphabetic, nothing happens, and the program proceeds like normal. I also do not know how to check if the input is longer than 2 characters in the try/except loop as it is very new to me. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    list = []
    def users_name():
      while True:
        try:
          name = str(input("Please enter your first name: "))
          list.append(name)
          break
        except TypeError:
          print("Letters only please.")
          continue
        except EOFError:
          print("Please input something....")
          continue

    users_name()
```

Comment: A string can contain any characters, so `str()` accepts any characters (not only letters).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow Only Alpha Characters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382696/allow-only-alpha-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You program will continue to run because of the `continue` clause in the `catch` block.

You can also check to see if the length of what they entered is longer than two characters.

```
list = []
def users_name():
  while True: # Never ending loop
    try:
      name = str(input("Please enter your first name: "))
      if (len(name) > 2)
          list.append(name)
      break
    except TypeError:
      print("Letters only please.")
      continue # This causes it to continue
    except EOFError:
      print("Please input something....")
      continue # This causes it to continue

users_name()
```

Also, you might want to stop the loop somehow. Maybe put in a `break` clause when you insert into the array?

```
if(len(name) > 2)
    list.append(name)
    break
...
```

To check if the input is a digit or an alphabet character use `isdigit()` or `isalpha()`

```
if a.isalpha():
    #do something
elif a.isdigit():
    #do something
```

Your code will then look like this:

```
list = []
def users_name():
while True: # Never ending loop
  try:
    name = str(input("Please enter your first name: "))
    if (len(name) > 2 && name.isalpha()):
        list.append(name)
        break
    else:
        raise TypeError
  except TypeError:
    print("Letters only please.")
    continue # This causes it to continue
  except EOFError:
    print("Please input something....")
    continue # This causes it to continue

users_name()
```

Also if you are using Python < 3 consider using `raw_input()`. `input()` will actually evaluate the input as Python code.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains it really well :)

Comment: @Valkiyare I Hope it helps/works! I don't have Python at my office, but I know enough to hopefully not cause any errors!

Comment: It works really well thank you, I've modified it for other inputs too :)

Answer (score 0):

To check the length of your String you can use the method `len()` to obtain its character length. You can then select those that are greater than 2 or your desired length.

To check if you string has only alphabetic characters you can use the `str.isalpha()` method to check so.

Therefore, if you check `len(name) > 2 and name.isalpha()` will help you filter those string that do not match what you want:

```
>>> name = "MyName"
>>> len(name) > 2 and name.isalpha()
True
>>> wrong_name = "My42Name"
>>> len(wrong_name) > 2 and wrong_name.isalpha()
False
>>> short_name = "A"
>>> len(short_name) > 2 and short_name.isalpha()
False
```