# How to check if a string is word with regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to check if a string (like 'hello') input by user only contains one word and nothing else. Like only true for those contains only [a-zA-Z] and no whitespace or dot or underscore or another word.

For example:

```
'hello' true
'hello_' false
'hello world' false
'h.e.l.l.o' false
```

I don't know how to write the regex. Need help.

Comment: You wrote it in your question, just add `+` to it: `[a-zA-Z]+`. You may also want to anchor it: `^[a-zA-Z]+$`.

Comment: No need for a regex. `str.isalpha` will do.

Comment: Is `hllo` a word `true` or `false`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow Only Alpha Characters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382696/allow-only-alpha-characters-in-python)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem why did you delete your answer? It was perfectly valid.

Comment: @ctwheels: no, it would also match diacritics.

Comment: @usr2564301 true. i want a string with [a-zA-Z].

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that may be what the OP is searching for. I understand they wrote `a-zA-Z`, but even if it's not what the OP is searching for maybe it will help another user. Just write a note letting users know that it matches Unicode characters and the `Lm`, `Lt`, `Lu`, `Ll`, `Lo` categories. Or just add logic from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii) post to your answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah str.isalpha solved my problem perfectly. I don't think i will ever encounter any diacritics in this problem since the string is part of url. I would accept your answer anyway. but thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to write a regex here. This is already builtin in Python with [**`str.isalpha`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> Return `True` if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, `False` otherwise.

So we can check it with:

```
if your_string.isalpha():
    pass
```

Note however that:

> **Note**: `str.isalpha` also includes diacritics, etc. For example:
>
> ```
> >>> 'ä'.isalpha()
> True
> ```
>
> this is not *per se* a problem. But it can be something to take into account.

In case you do not want diacricics, you can for instance check that all characters have an `ord(..)` less than 128 as well:

```
if your_string.isalpha() and all(ord(c) < 128 for c in your_string):
    pass
```

The advantage of using builtins is that these are more self-explaining (`isalpha()` clearly suggests what it is doing), and furthermore it is very unlikely to contain any bugs (I am not saying that other approaches *do* contain bugs, but writing something yourself, typically means it is not tested very effectively, hence it can still not fully cover *edge* and *corner* cases).

Comment: Nitpick: This will also accept accented letters, umlauts, and probably a bunch more, but maybe that's exactly what OP actually wants. (I did not mean that that's wrong, just wanted to point this out.)

Comment: You can remove diacritics from the string using the methods discussed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196345/how-to-check-if-a-string-in-python-is-in-ascii) if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the anchors `^` and `$`:

```
import re
s = "hello"
if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+$', s):
   pass #string condition met
```

Performance comparisons between `re.findall` and `re.search`:

```
import timeit
s1 = """
import re
re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+$', 'hello')
"""
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s1,number=10000))
>>> 0.0147941112518

s2 = """
import re
re.match('^[a-zA-Z]+$', 'hello')
"""
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=s2,number=10000))
>>> 0.0134868621826
```

While `re.match` performs slightly better than `re.findall`, I prefer `re.findall` as 1) it is easier to view the results initially and 2) immediately store the results in a list.

Comment: But using `match` you don't need `^` and `$`, and a list is not necessary (if only because since you *must* test an entire string, it can only occur zero or one time).